# mariadb | docker-compose - not creating db user/database on dockr-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

currently im trying to setup a database for use with one of my
projects rn, ive setup one before... but i forgot how i ran it/set it up

going off of my current docker-compose file for my other project i have this
ready to be used

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
    project-mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.3.16
        stop_grace_period: 45s
        volumes:
          - projectdb-1:/var/lib/mysql/
          - projectsocket-1:/var/run/mysqld/
          - ./src/database/conf/mysql/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/:ro
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=stackrootpassword
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=projectdb
          - MYSQL_USER=projectadmin
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=stackpassword
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "13362:3306"
  
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_external_network

volumes: 
    projectdb-1:
    projectsocket-1:
```

but upon running docker-compose build/docker-compose up -d
when i docker exec into the instance and go into mysql
my user or database does not get created

what ive tried
`docker-compose down -v`
`docker volume rm <volume>`
`docker-compose up -d`

The result of these are ending up with this log inside of docker

```
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 24M, instances = 1, chunk size = 24M
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1630860; transaction id 21
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201202  0:33:15
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@volume' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 6 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 6
project-mariadb_1  | 2020-12-02  0:33:15 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
project-mariadb_1  | Version: '10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

ive tried mariadb:latest/10.4/10.4.8/10.3.16
all give me the same issue.

hope i gave enough detail in this

Kind regards,
Phil

Comment: How you verify it not work?

Comment: @atline I did docker exec i said and did the mysql show databases command and tried connecting with the user i set in the env

Comment: `mysql -u projectadmin -p` could not access the database? If that, I don't know, the only information I could give you is if delete `- ./src/database/conf/mysql/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/:ro` which I could not simulate, all things ok on my side..., so is `show databases`

Comment: @atline i did what you said and deleted that line, recreated etc and still nothing
heres my mysql https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/783504427444469801/783523573243183104/unknown.png

Comment: No idea, my side shows `projectdb` is already in database... You may wait other guys to give inspire... Or maybe you could try on another pc to see if possible different results, then compare. I fail to find the difference between you and me.

Comment: @atline so good news i got it sort of working. it was apparently my password causing the issue. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was using a password that i guess messed up the mysql/mariadb setup
and a weird admin username!